# Multiple Underlined Tooltips on one control - WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

I would like a control that shows.

**Tooltip1** notooltip **Tooltip2**

```
   ^             ^
TOOLTIPA      TOOLTIPB
```

To have one tooltip display when hovering over tooltip1 and a different one display when over tooltip2.  In reality these would both be underlined and blue.

I can accomplish this with a richtextbox and tracking the locations of tooltips by GetPositionFromCharIndex and mouse events.  However, with the richtextbox I can't disable text selection / position caret without disabling the control, which in turn disables all of my events.

I don't want to use multiple labels because it requires manually spacing the labels because of handling character spacing.

Is there a third party control like Dev Express that might handle this?  Any alternatives?

Thanks

Comment: Did you get this working to your satisfaction? I'm creating a user control that owner draws a color palette. It would be nice to show a different tooltip over each color. I can call Tooltip.Show(), but once it hides itself, it won't show again until the mouse leaves and reenters my control.

Comment: I am finishing it up.  I ended up using TextRenderer to draw the string I wanted and keep track of the different Tooltip locations.  It shouldn't be to bad to modify it for your use.  What would be a good way to share the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking for from your description, but it seems that you want one control that has a ToolTip who's caption depends on what part of the control the mouse is hovering over?

I can't think of a "good" way to do this. The code below will work for a Label, but it's ugly. I'd personally rather create a UserControl with multiple Labels and worry about manually spacing them. But here's what I got:

```
        Label lbl = new Label() { Left = 6, Top = 6, AutoSize = true };
        this.Controls.Add(lbl);

        // Determine the width of each of the "sections" of the Label Text.
        // Use the fact that AutoSize = true will increase the Width of the
        //  Label as you increase the Text Length.
        int width = lbl.Width;
        lbl.Width = 0;
        lbl.Text = string.Empty;
        lbl.Text = "x";
        int delta = lbl.Width;
        lbl.Text += "x";
        delta = lbl.Width - 2 * (lbl.Width - delta);
        lbl.Text = "ToolTip1";
        int txt1Width = lbl.Width - delta;
        delta = lbl.Width;
        lbl.Text += " NoToolTip ";
        int txt2Width = lbl.Width - delta;
        delta = lbl.Width;
        lbl.Text += "ToolTip2";
        int txt3Width = lbl.Width - delta;

        // Use a System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip and set the caption on 
        //  MouseHover, depending on the Position of the Cursor.
        var tip = new ToolTip();
        lbl.MouseHover += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tip.RemoveAll();

            // Find the Point for the ToolTip (relative to the Label) based
            //  on the Position of the Cursor.
            this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
            Point lblScreenPos = lbl.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
            Point tipPoint = new Point(Cursor.Position.X, Cursor.Position.Y + lbl.Height);
            tipPoint = new Point(tipPoint.X - lblScreenPos.X, tipPoint.Y - lblScreenPos.Y);

            // Determine the location of the "sections" of Label text.
            int x = tipPoint.X;
            int txt1Left = 3;
            int txt1Right = txt1Left + txt1Width;
            int txt3Left = txt1Right + txt2Width;
            int txt3Right = txt3Left + txt3Width;

            // Show the ToolTip with the correct caption.
            if (x >= txt1Left && x <= txt1Right)
            {
                tip.Show("TOOLTIPA", lbl, tipPoint, tip.AutoPopDelay);
            }
            else if (x >= txt3Left && x <= txt3Right)
            {
                tip.Show("TOOLTIPB", lbl, tipPoint, tip.AutoPopDelay);
            }
        };
        lbl.MouseLeave += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) { tip.RemoveAll(); };
```

The ToolTip is not underlined and the system default font is automatically used. This can only be overridden by owner-drawing the ToolTip. If you need to make it blue and underline it, check out the [OwnerDraw](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.ownerdraw%28VS.90%29.aspx) property.

Comment: This is close to what I was doing with the richtextbox.  But I am actually looking to underline the text of the label for where the tool will display. Kind of like a link.  That is why I used a rich textbox so I could change font partway through.  But then I am stuck with the caret position and selectable text.

Comment: Use 2 LinkLabels and 1 Label. Place them on the Form in the correct spot with code. Determine where to place the Controls with code similar to mine that gets the widths of the "sections" of Text of my Label. Find the width of one space, the distance between the left edge of the Control and the drawn Text (This is 3 pixels), and the distance between the right edge of the Control and the drawn Text (Control Width - Text width - 3). Use these 3 values to determine where to place the next Control so that the drawn Text will be exactly one space after that of the last Control.

Comment: I tried this, or at least I put a label with all of the text on the form, then manually lined up multiple labels to see where their location was relative to the previous label's location / width.  The value changed each time due to character spacing logic I assume.  Sometimes it would be 6 pixels, other times it would be 4. ( Note I turned off padding on all of my labels.

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by using a richtextbox control with all of the text in it.  I then insert labels onto the form by using the GetPositionFromCharIndex from the richtextbox to place the labels.

Comment: I am sorry, you are correct.  I am finding that is always the location + width - 7 for the start of the next label ( This is not using trim, trim would be 4 pixels ).  However, if I trim and the font changes, I don't know how big that space is ( By default for me it is 3 pixels ).

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're after:

```
ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
toolTip.SetToolTip(control1, "Hello ");
toolTip.SetToolTip(control2, "world!");
```

...or am I missing the boat entirely here? It's a bit hard to understand what the problem is from your description.

Comment: I don't know a good way to describe it but basically a control that shows three words, where hovering over the first word displays one tooltip, and hovering over the third word would display a different tooltip.  I also want word 1 & 3 underlined, but no tooltip or underline on word 2...